# Why does my code go straight to the end condition?

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js

So, I'm making a 2D shooter video game in Processing, and I want the score to be the reason as to how you move to the next level. I have the levels into an Array, and have a couple of Int elements to define the levels as well.

However, as soon as the score reaches 200 (The desired score to move to the next level) It goes straight to WIN and it doesn't go through any of the levels.

Here is the main code:

```js
import ddf.minim.spi.*;
import ddf.minim.signals.*;
import ddf.minim.*;

final int LEVEL_ONE=0;
final int LEVEL_TWO=1;
final int LEVEL_THREE=2;
final int WON=3;
final int LOST=4;

final String WIN="You Beat the System!";
final String LOSE="Totes, Awkes...";

int gameState;


Level l;

ArrayList <Level> levels = new ArrayList<Level>();

void setup() {
  size(1000, 500);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  loadAssets();



  Level l1 = new Level("LEVEL 1", 5, 0, 3);
  Level l2 = new Level("LEVEL 2", 3, 3, 1);
  Level l3 = new Level("LEVEL 3", 5, 7, 0);

  levels.add(l1);
  levels.add(l2);
  levels.add(l3);


  l = levels.get(0);
}


void winCurrentLevel() {
  levels.remove(l);



  if (levels.size() > 0) l=levels.get(0);
  else winGame();
}



void draw() {
  switch(gameState) {
  case WON:
    showScreen(WIN);
    break;
  case LOST:
    showScreen(LOSE);
    break;
  default:
    l.playLevel();
  }
}
```

And this is the code for the Level:

```js
class Level {


  final int GAMEPLAY=0;
  final int INTRO=-1;

  int lvlState;
  Background bg;

  ArrayList<PowerUps> powerups;
  ArrayList<Enemy> enemies;
  ArrayList<Bomb> bombs;

  //Score
  int score;
  //Intro
  int introTimer;
  String intro;

  //Enemies and PowerUps
  int numEnem;
  int enemySpawn;
  int numCoffees;


  // Bomb Enemies and Large Powerups
  int numBomb;
  int numLargeCoffees;



  //scrollforce
  int scrollrate;
  int scroll;
  PVector scrollForce;

  Level(String intromessage, int numenemies, int numbombs, int numcol) {

    powerups= new ArrayList<PowerUps>();
    enemies= new ArrayList<Enemy>();  
    bombs= new ArrayList<Bomb>();


    introTimer=60;
    lvlState=INTRO;


    intro=intromessage;

    numEnem=numenemies;
    numBomb=numbombs;

    numCoffees=numcol;
    scrollrate=1;
    scrollForce=new PVector(-4, 0);
    enemySpawn=100;


    initializePowerUps();
    spawnEnemies();
    spawnBombs();
  }


  void playLevel() {
    if (score==200) nextLevel();
    switch(lvlState) {
    case INTRO:
      if (introTimer>0) 
      {
        introTimer--;
        showScreen(intro);
      } else if (introTimer==0) lvlState=GAMEPLAY;
      break;
    case GAMEPLAY:
      gamePlay();
      break;
    }
  }



  void gamePlay() {
    background(255);

    if (scroll<8) scroll=scrollrate;
    if (frameCount%120==0) scrollrate*=1.5;

    p.update();



    for (int i=0; i<enemies.size(); i++) {
      Enemy e=enemies.get(i);
      e.update();
      if (e.pos.x<100) {
        enemies.remove(this);
        p.takeDamage(1);
      }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<bombs.size(); i++) {
      Bomb b=bombs.get(i);
      b.update();
      if (b.pos.x<100) {
        bombs.remove(this);
        b.takeDamage(1);
      }
    }


    if (frameCount%enemySpawn==60) spawnEnemies();
    if (frameCount%enemySpawn==60) spawnBombs();


    //Trying to change to level two
 


    for (int i=0; i<powerups.size(); i++) {
      PowerUps pu=powerups.get(i);
      pu.update();
    }

    drawHealthBar();
    drawScore();
    drawRayBar();
  }


  void spawnBombs() {
    while (bombs.size()<numBomb) {
      bombs.add(new Bomb(new PVector(random(800, 1000), random(50, 450)), new PVector (-random(7, 12), 0), Bomb));
    }
  }


  void spawnEnemies() {
    while (enemies.size()<numEnem) {
      enemies.add(new Enemy(new PVector(random(800, 1000), random(50, 450)), new PVector (-random(5, 10), 0), Grenade));
    }
  }

  void initializePowerUps() {
    spawnCoffee(numCoffees);
  }

  void spawnCoffee(int spawn) {
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
      powerups.add(new Coffee(new PVector(-width, random(height-SmallCoffee.height)), new PVector (-random(5, 10), 0), SmallCoffee));
    }
  }
  void nextLevel() {
   if (gameState == LEVEL_ONE)
   {
   enemies.clear();
   bombs.clear();
   powerups.clear();
   
   p.health=p.MAX_HEALTH;
   gameState = LEVEL_TWO;
   } else if (gameState==LEVEL_TWO) {
   gameState=WON;
   }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice this line:

```
if (score==200) nextLevel();
```

This check is performed by **every** level. So as soon as you reach `200`, you go to the next level, where you perform this check, and then go to the next level, where you perform this check...

Instead, you need to have a **different** value for each level. You can either do a check like this:

```
if(level == 1 && score == 200){
   nextLevel();
}
else if(level == 2 && score == 500){
  nextLevel();
}
//...
```

Or better yet, you should pass a value into your `Level` class that tells you the value needed to go to the next level.